# Trace the changes in sign of $\cos^2A-\sin^2A$

Tags: trigonometry

This problem is found in S.L. Loney's book on Plane Trigonometry. The goal is to trace the changes in sign of the expression $\sin^2A – \cos^2A$ as $\theta$ increases in value. When I tackled the problem myself, I expressed the above more concisely as $\cos2A$.

Now, the cosine of an angle is positive in the first and fourth quadrants; hence $2n\pi – $$\pi\over2$$ \le 2\theta \le 2n\pi + $$\pi\over2$. When I isolated $\theta$, I found the following result:
$n\pi – $$\pi\over4$$\le \theta \le n\pi +$$ \pi\over 4$. To tell the truth, my problem is laughable. Because I only request to know how I am supposed to correctly map this information on rectangular axes.

The $n\pi$ part of the inequality represents two positions the revolving line can take, and I have only ever dealt with the revolving line taking only one position; Hence I don't know how to deal with some such question. I did however conjure a solution; yet, the solution isn't based on reasoning, and more on mere convincement. I found it only reasonable to ask this here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, $\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=\cos2\theta$.

You may consider the graph of function $f(\theta)=\cos2\theta$, which has a period of $\pi$ because $$\cos(2(\theta+\pi))=\cos(2\theta+2\pi)=\cos2\theta.$$
In the period $\left(-\dfrac\pi4,\dfrac{3\pi}4\right]$, when $\theta\in\left(-\dfrac\pi4,\dfrac\pi4\right)$, $2\theta\in\left(-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right)$, so $\cos2\theta>0$. When $\theta=\dfrac\pi4$, $\cos2\theta=0$. When $\theta\in\left(\dfrac\pi4,\dfrac{3\pi}4\right)$, $2\theta\in\left(\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac{3\pi}2\right)$, so $\cos2\theta<0$. When $\theta=\dfrac{3\pi}4$, $\cos2\theta=0$.

That is to say, $\cos2\theta\begin{cases}>0,&\theta\in\left(-\dfrac\pi4+k\pi,\dfrac\pi4+k\pi\right).\\[5pt]=0,&\theta=\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}4.\\<0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$ where $k$ is an integer.

As I see that the title doesn't match the beginning of the question, you'll need to reverse the signs if you're solving for $\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta$.